# Output of System.out.println(object)

Tags: java, object

I want to know what exactly the output is when I do the following.

```
class Data {
  int a = 5;
}

class Main {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    data dObj = new data();
    System.out.println(dObj);
  }
}
```

I know it gives something related to object as the output in my case is *data@1ae73783*. I guess the *1ae73783* is a hex number. I also did some work around and printed

```
System.out.println(dObj.hashCode());
```

I got the number *415360643*. I got an integer value. I don't know what `hashCode()` returns, still out of curiosity, when I converted *1ae73783* to decimal, I got *415360643*!

That's why I am curious about what exactly is this number. Is this some memory location of Java's sandbox or some other thing?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/q/29140402/238704

Answer (score 17, accepted):

What happens is that the default [`toString()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#toString%28%29) method of your class is getting used. This method is defined as follows:

> The `toString` method for class `Object` returns a string consisting of the name of the class of which the object is an instance, the at-sign character `@', and the unsigned hexadecimal representation of the hash code of the object. In other words, this method returns a string equal to the value of:
>
> ```
> getClass().getName() + '@' + Integer.toHexString(hashCode())
> ```

The value returned by the default [`hashCode()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#hashCode%28%29) method is implementation-specific:

> As much as is reasonably practical, the `hashCode` method defined by class `Object` does return distinct integers for distinct objects. (This is typically implemented by converting the internal address of the object into an integer, but this implementation technique is not required by the JavaTM programming language.)

Comment: Yes, this is almost the same as I experimented later, I did `code`System.out.println(String.valueOf(Integer.parseInt("1ae73783",16))); `code` and got the decimal value

Answer (score 3):

When you print an instance of your class, that does not override the `toString` method, then the `toString` method of `Object` class is used. Which prints an output in the form: -

```
data@1ae73783
```

- The first part of that `output` shows the type of the object.
- And the 2nd part is the hexadecimal representation of the `hashCode`
  of your object.

Here's the source code of `Object.toString()` method, that you can find in the installation directory of your `jdk`, under `src` folder: -

```
public String toString() {
    return getClass().getName() + "@" + Integer.toHexString(hashCode());
}
```

Answer (score 3):

The Javadoc for [hashCode()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#hashCode%28%29) and [toString()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#toString%28%29) in the `Object` class should be able to clarify this for you.

Answer (score 2):

That code calls the default `toString()` implementation of the `Object` class, that is:

```
public String toString() {
    return getClass().getName() + "@" + Integer.toHexString(hashCode());
}
```