# Not getting complete array while using it as variable

Tags: java, arrays

I newbie in Java and learning it.
I got a question related to array, can you please look into it?

I am getting following output: [[Ljava.lang.String;@7a982589
from below code:

```
String[][] multi = new String [][] {
{ "Scenarios", "Description", "1.0", "1.1", "1.2"},
{ "S1", "Verify hotel search", "Y", "Y", "Y"},
};
System.out.println(multi);
```

While if I place following:

```
System.out.println(multi[0][1]);
```

I am getting correct output.
Description.

Now, why I am not getting entire array through "multi" variable.

Comment: A relevant question of what is going on: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13498179/output-of-system-out-printlnobject

Answer (score 1):

Use this util method, cause you have a 2D array. Read the api [Arrays#deepToString(Object[])](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#deepToString%28java.lang.Object%5B%5D%29)

```
Arrays.deepToString(multi);
```

> Returns a string representation of the "deep contents" of the
>   specified array. **If the array contains other arrays as elements, the
>   string representation contains their contents and so on. This method
>   is designed for converting multidimensional arrays to strings**.

Answer (score 0):

What you're seeing is the default toString() of arrays. If you want it pretty-printed, use `Arrays.deepToString(arr);`

Answer (score 0):

That is because,instead of printing the value stored in the array, you are printing the state of the array. That is when you say
`System.out.println(multi);`
it implicitly means
`System.out.println(multi.toString());`

Answer (score 0):

Use [`java.util.Arrays.deepToString(multi)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#deepToString%28java.lang.Object%5b%5d%29).  What you're seeing is the default `Object.toString()` since arrays don't override `toString()`.

Answer (score 0):

System.out.println calls toString on object arguments to get their textual representation. Java arrays are also objects and they inherit toString from java.lang.Object:

```
public String toString() {
    return getClass().getName() + "@" + Integer.toHexString(hashCode());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

multi will hold the reference to the array itself, and  multi[0][1] will refer to the element in the array

Answer (score 0):

access each item from array and print it out:

```
for(int i=0;i<2;i++){
            for(int j=0;j<5;j++){
                System.out.println(multi[i][j]);
            }
        }
```