# can anybody explain why i get random ar.get(0) value

Tags: java, arraylist, collections

I am new to java and try to use ArrayList but I get random output when running no error I got but random output I got when trying to access ar.grt(0) value .can anyone explain it why I got this type of output

```
import java.util.*;
import java.util.Comparator;
import java.lang.*;
import java.io.*;


class Student
{

     String name="";
     int roll;
     int marks;
     public Student(String na,int ro,int ma)
     {
        name=na;
        roll=ro;
        marks=ma;   

     }

}

public class CustomSortingClass
{
    public static void main(String []args)
    {   Student s1=new Student("Priyanka",05,75);
        Student s2=new Student("Abhishek",01,90);
        Student s3=new Student("Shivendra",04,80);
        Student s4=new Student("Ritesh",02,95);
        Student s5=new Student("Sonali",06,65);



        ArrayList<Student> ar=new ArrayList<Student>();
        ar.add(s1);
        ar.add(s2);
        ar.add(s3);
        ar.add(s4);
        ar.add(s5);

        System.out.println("unsorted Student\n"+ar.get(0));

    }

}
```

output is :

```
F:\java>java CustomSortingClass

unsorted Student

Student@b065c63**
```

Comment: Each element added added to your ArrayList **ar** contains an instance of a Student object as outlined by the Student class. Each Student object instance consists of a **Name**, **Roll**, and **Marks** again, as outlined by your Student class via class member variables. To properly view the contents of the Student object instance contained within any ArrayList element you might do something like this: `System.out.println("unsorted Student\n" + "Name: " + ar.get(2).name
+ "\nRoll: " + ar.get(2).roll + "\nMarks: " + ar.get(2).marks);`.

Answer (score 1):

The random value that you are getting is the `hashCode` of the object since you are printing the whole object, but you have not defined what to print.

Therefore, the default implementation, when an Object is printed is

`getClass().getName() + "@" + Integer.toHexString(hashCode())`

which is what you would be getting exactly.

Comment: can u correct my code ..

Comment: your code is fine :) it's not incorrect. If you want better output, you will need to define the toString for your object. Please read more on https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13498179/output-of-system-out-printlnobject

Comment: how can i print value of s1 object of arraylist ...

Comment: @AbhishekBais `s1` is an object, you are already getting the standard representation of it. You must first define what you want printed, its name? its roll? its mark?

Comment: thanks guys now understood ...confusion arise due to websites which print object directly.

Comment: This is missing the most important point, this is the implemntation of `Object.toString` and can be overridden to printe whatever we want for an instance..

Answer (score -1):

```
ar.add(s1)
```

should instead be

```
ar.add(s1.name)
```

Comment: `s1.name` is `String`, you can't add it to list of `Student`.

Comment: Right, sorry, the ArrayList type would be changed to ```String```

Comment: No, it shouldn't. The only thing to change is the print.

Comment: So how should the code be changed?

Comment: i want to store all three value at one arraylist element [name ,roll, marks]....i searches online alot and same code is also there but their output is like [alex, brian, charles]

Comment: As I wrote in the comment above, you need to change the print. Look at the question I linked as a duplicate. @AbhishekBais

Comment: `System.out.println("unsorted Student\n" + ar.get(0).name); (despite having a proper `toString()` is recommended)